# How to search mails from mailbox using Subject line

Tags: php, imap

I am using IMAP to read a mailbox.

Now is it possible that I can search mailbox with `SUBJECT LINE and FROM name` as flag ?

**Example**: is it possible to define search criteria :
`imap_search($login,'SUBJECT '.$sub.' FROM'.$ToSearch)`;
Is it allowed to use from name and subject in search for an email ?

Comment: the way i tried does not worked please suggest how can it be done

Comment: $some   = imap_search($conn, 'SUBJECT "HOWTO be Awesome" SINCE "8 August 2008"', SE_UID); use this might be it help but combition of both subject and from name i don't think work

Comment: It should, but make you are quoting both arguments of SUBJECT and FROM.

Comment: Or even better, use literals, if you ever need to search anything that isn't ascii.

Answer (score 1):

See the [SEARCH Command](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501#section-6.4.4) section of [RFC 3501](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501) to see how to use search functionality in IMAP. An `AND` operation is implicit so you can just put conditions next to each other:

```
0001 SEARCH SUBJECT "hello world" FROM "john"
```

If you want an `OR` operation instead, you need to prefix the criteria with the `OR` keyword:

```
0002 SEARCH OR SUBJECT "hello world" FROM "john"
```

Note that strings are used as substring search, i.e. the `FROM` in these cases will match both `"john"` and `"john@malta.com"`.