# imap_search - search SUBJECT and FROM

Tags: php, imap

How to search SUBJECT and FROM in PHP?

```
imap_search($this->imap, 'FROM "text" SUBJECT "text"');
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to search mails from mailbox using Subject line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23896530/how-to-search-mails-from-mailbox-using-subject-line)

Comment: Those examples not work

Comment: What kind of errors do you get? What have you tried? There are a lot of questions and answers with imap_search() to check out: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=imap_search

Answer (score 0):

`Or` is implicit in imap while doing search without any operator, so your code should be working. Are you sure `"text"` is present in a `from` or in a `subject` ?

You can also do it explicitely by prepending your query with `OR`:

```
imap_search($this->imap, 'OR FROM "text" SUBJECT "text"');
```